# How to deal with default bool value using EFCore when false doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When use EFCore, set the property in Entity default true, when a new record need to add,
give the property false, it will always generate 1 to SQLServer.

Comment: Show us your code, preferably a [mcve]

Comment: This is a well known EFC behavior, what EFC version are you using?

Comment: With an explicit `bool? _backing;` field.